# How to enable php extensions and database support?

Tags: php, mysql, osx-lion

After spending some time in setting up a local sever in mac os, installing php5, and finally installing mysql I am still running on problems when trying to perform an drupal install.

When going to install.php the page shows the following

> PHP extensions  Disabled
>
> Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system
>      requirements page for more information):
>      gd

And;

> Database support    Disabled.
>
> Your web server does not appear to support any common PDO database extensions. Check with
>      your hosting provider to see if they support PDO (PHP Data Objects) and offer any databases
>      that Drupal supports.

Any ideas on how to proceed with the installation?

More information:

> php5 and php5-gd were installed via macports. mysql was installed via homebrew.

Comment: If you are using Debian, you can solve this installing the extension from command line: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

Comment: for me, it was about installing the `php-pdo_pgsql` package (to provide the `pdo_pgsql.so` php module) and uncommenting (`extension=pdo_pgsql`, line 912) exactly in `/etc/php-7.2.ini` file (and not in the customly-created `/etc/php-7.2/drupal.ini`, unlike with `gd`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two more packages to pass through this error message:

**php5-gd** and **php5-mysql**.

So just install it and you'll not get any error.

**Note:** You can replace **php5-mysql** to other package based on the database you are using.

For example:

```
php5-sqlite for sqlite
php5-pgsql for postgres
php5-adodb for ADOdb database
```

Comment: FYI for version 8.5.3 of Drupal just use the commands like this: apt-get install php-sqlite (without specifying the version number of PHP).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well when trying to manually setup drupal, apache, mysql and php on windows, even after uncommenting extension=php_gd2.dll, extension=php_mbstring.dll and extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll from the Dynamic Extensions section

In order to fix this, I had to change the **extension_dir** in my **php.ini** to explicitly state the folder path of the extensions:

From:

```
extension_dir = "./ext"
```

To:

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/php-5.3.28-Win32-VC9-x86/ext"
```

Comment: I was getting the same error. Putting full path of the extension directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your build of php5 doesn't enable gd and pdo-mysql as default, so what you need to do is re-configure your php5 with two extra config:

```
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
--with-gd
```

and then 'make&&sudo make install'

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that? How can I reconfigure my php5? Could you write the specific commands? Edit: Typo.

Comment: Can you give more information like how did you install php5 and mysql, via sources? macports? or homebrew? So I can give more details based on your specific situation.

Comment: php5 and php5-gd were installed via macports. mysql was installed via homebrew.

Comment: You can try with "sudo port install php5 +gd +mysql5"

Comment: If you are using Debian, **is not necessary to recompile**, just install the extension from CLI: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

Answer (score 0):

**Error:PHP extensions disabled: gd**

Install `php-gd` package. Post installing if the error persists, un-comment the following line in /etc/php/php.ini

`extension=gd.so`

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini I added

extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"

And uncommented

extension=pdo_mysql
extension=gd2

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you install XAMPP which has prebuilt Apache, PHP5, MySQL from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html?